# Kentico 11: Default Setting for Product Coupons > "Apply lower priority discounts"

Tags: e-commerce, product, kentico, coupon, discount

Kentico 11.0.34 version. In the Product Coupons app, the default setting for "Apply lower priority discounts" is true/yes. Business logic stipulates that this should be set to false/no except in extraordinary circumstances. Because this option is hidden under the Discount processing tab at setup, it is often missed. Is it possible to change the default of this setting? [Discount Processing Setting Default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqyny.png)

Answer (score 0):

Default value unfortunately can not be changed via UI. You can get to property of discounts table in the UI (Modules -> E-commerce -> classes -> discounts), but general attributes can not be [modified and are grayed out](http://prntscr.com/pk3onr). Without DB hacks or direct change of class configuration in CMS_Class table it can not be done and I would like to avoid that (upgrades etc.) In code, default property getter if value is null will return true.

What is the situation in which you want this to be disabled? There could some things achieved via code and attached handlers for example, but it depends on situation.